# Codeigniter - can't set rules in primary key column

Tags: codeigniter

I have trouble with codeigniter's set rules form validation while i'm trying to set on my primary key column.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('pgw_nip', 'pgw_nip','required|is_unique|max_length[25]');
```

i got error message on my form_validation rules. while i'm not using that rule, it working well.

Comment: what message? the fact that you're getting "A" message gives us exactly zero information about what the problem may be. Unless you can show the exact message you're getting, there's not much help we can give you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This because of ***failed to load relevant library***

**Method 01**

```
public function  __construct()
{
     parent::__construct();
     $this->load->library('form_validation');
     $this->load->helper('form');
}
```

**Method 02**

in `application/config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation');
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form');
```

[Form_Validation Codeigniter](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html)